# Go to directory of a file path

Tags: bash, cd

Is there a way a `cd` command may accept a regular file path
and jump to the dir where the file resides?

Image you could do:

`vim /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module
cd <alt>+<.> # for last command argument
git add <alt>+<.>`

would love that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an approach that’s a little less typing, but you need to be a bit careful with it. 
It involves the `!$` history reference (which jcbermu also used),
which means the last word of the most recent command. 
(This is available in most shells: definitely `bash`, `csh`, and `tcsh`.) 
Append the `:h` modifier to remove a trailing file name component,
leaving only the **h**ead, and your command is `cd !$:h`.

In the following examples, the bold text is what you type:

```
~ $ vim /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module
                (edit the file)
~ $ cd !$:h
cd /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy
/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy $
```

It can handle spaces in the directory name, up to a point:

```
~ $ vim /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/old\ code/legacy.module
                (edit the file)
~ $ cd !$:h
cd /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/old\ code
/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/old code $
```

or

```
~ $ vim /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/"old code"/legacy.module
                (edit the file)
~ $ cd !$:h
cd /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/"old code"
/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/old code $
```

But, I think a good general statement is that it fails if the last `/` in the filename is quoted:

```
~ $ vim "/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/old code/legacy.module"
                (edit the file)
~ $ cd !$:h
cd "/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/old code
> Ctrl+C        (Shell asks for continuation text
                    because it sees an unmatched quote character.)
```

It also fails if the file is in the current directory:

```
~ $ vim legacy.module
        (edit the file)
~ $ cd !$:h
cd legacy.module
-bash: cd: legacy.module: No such file or directory
~ $                 (:h has no effect because !$ doesn’t contain a /)
```

but that’s trivial. 
If the file is in the current directory, you just wouldn’t do the `cd` at all. 
Another problem would be if you put the filename into a variable:

```
~ $ fn=/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module
~ $ vim "$fn"
        (edit the file)
~ $ cd !$:h
cd "$fn"
-bash: cd: /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module: Not a directory
~ $                 (:h has no effect because !$ (which is "$fn") doesn’t contain a /)
```

You can handle this as follows:

```
~ $ fn=/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module
~ $ vim 
        (edit the file)
~ $ cd "${fn%/*}"
/usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy $
```

As the other answers suggested, use `.` or `"$PWD"` for the `git add` command.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

Create a shell script "cdfile" containing `cd "$(dirname "$1")"`, make it executable and put it somewhere, where it will be found.

Now use

```
vim /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module
cdfile <alt>+<.> # for last command attribute
git add .
```

Comment: You could also just create a shell function with the same name.

Comment: @slhck Yes, you could - but it would reduce the usefullnes to the shell. Using a separate executable file makes the functionality available for every context

Comment: I've got the "cdfile" as listed above, but it seems it changes the cwd just in the subshell - is that possible?

Comment: Absolutely: it is not only possible, but inevitable and predictable that a `cd` in a shell script will affect only the rest of the script -- and if the script is only that one command, then "the rest of the script" is nothing. A script cannot affect the working directory of the parent shell that invokes the script.

Comment: Depending on how you call the script - if you have no hashbang at the start you don't create a subshell. It definitly works here on CentOS 6.4 standard installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to extract the directory name from the file name, it's called dirname

```
cd `dirname /your/file/path`
```

Comment: This will break if the directory name contains a space in its path.

Comment: True, it was meant more like an example, a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Using `dirname` and `!$`:

```
vim /usr/share/drupal7/sites/all/modules/legacy/legacy.module
cd "$(dirname !$)" 
git add "$PWD"
```

Comment: This will break if the directory or file name contain a space in their path. You need to quote the substitution properly.

Comment: Corrected for space on file name or directory name

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way to `cd` to a binary directory...

```
> cd "$(dirname "`which bash`")"
```